# Files not copying correctly with Java

Tags: java

I have written a little program that just reads a files contents and writes it to a new copy. This works perfectly with text files, but with PNGs and video files, it fails to correctly create the file (the image is all black or the video will not play). I know there are APIs that can copy files with one line, but I'd love to know why this isn't working. Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class CopyFile
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        File file = new File("test.mp4");
    File copy = new File("copy.mp4");

    InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file));
    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(copy));

    System.out.println(input.ready());

    while(input.ready())
    {
        int i = input.read();
        //System.out.print( (char) ( (byte) i));
        out.write(i);
    }

    input.close();
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Don't use `input.ready`, rely on what `input.read` is telling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Don't use `Reader` and `Writer` unless you know the input is text. Use `InputStream` and `OutputStream.`
2. Don't use `ready(),` or, for Sotirios' benefit, `available()` either. Neither of them is a valid test for end of stream. They both concern whether the input can be read *without blocking,* which isn't the same thing at all. See the Javadoc.
3. You're not detecting end of stream correctly. If `read()` returns -1 you're still copying that to the output.
4. Copying a single character or single byte at a time is extremely slow.

The canonical way to copy streams in Java is as follows:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

where `count` is an `int,` and `buffer` is a `byte[]` of any size greater than zero, typically 8192.

Answer (score 4):

`Reader`s and `Writer`s are for reading character streams (i.e., text). Pictures and videos are binary data, not text, and will probably be corrupted if you pass them through character streams. This is because, depending on the character set, there is not necessarily a reversible mapping between bytes and characters. Some byte sequences are gibberish if interpreted as characters, then gibberish gets written back to the file.

Use the `InputStream` and `OutputStream` that you open directly, instead of wrapping them up as a `Reader` and `Writer`, and it will work correctly. These are byte streams and can handle any type of data.

E.g.,

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(copy);
```

P.S. This will still be quite slow. You can wrap the streams in a `BufferedInputStream` and `BufferedOutputStream` for a simple way to improve performance, although the one-line copy APIs will probably still be faster.

Comment: You've identified one problem out of at least four.

Comment: @EJP 2 out of 3 by my count, but yup.